# Error regarding Float & Int in C Method

Tags: c, methods, compilation, int

So I'm trying to write a basic program in C with a method in it but keep getting errors when compiling the program which is due to how I have my method

I keep getting errors that say

```
curve.c: In function ‘compute_curve’:
curve.c:32:7: error: argument ‘f’ doesn’t match prototype
 float compute_curve(f)
       ^
curve.c:6:7: error: prototype declaration
float compute_curve(float);
```

I'm new to this compiling stuff so just curious as to where I'm screwing up the float and int's

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`. `float compute_curve(f)` should be `float compute_curve(float f)` Find out how to get your compiler to warn you about these things. Also, C functions aren't called "methods"; they're called "functions".

Comment: There is another bug not mentioned yet; `fclose(fp);` should come outside of the loop where it is in.  (Otherwise you close the file after the first iteration).

Comment: regarding this line: 'float f = 1.0;'  the '1.0' defines a double which must then be converted to float for the assignment to 'f'.  suggest using 'float f = 1.0f;'  where the final 'f' is a value modifier that makes the value a float

Comment: you need to be very careful about using the '=' when working with float values because many numbers cannot be exactly implemented in float nor in double.

Comment: this line: ' while (f != 0)' is comparing a float value with a integer value.  suggest using: '
  while (f != 0.0f)'

Comment: please be consistent with indentation.  (I suggest using 4 spaces for each level of indenting) such consistency makes the code much much easier to read/debug

Comment: in general C assumes that parameters (and return values) are integers.  that is the root of your compiling problem.  suggest using 'float compute_curve( float f)' for the first line of the compute_curve() function

Comment: when you compile with all the warnings enabled, you will see several warnings about code errors, like the compute_curve() function is missing the return (some float value) statement.  However, the main() function ignores the returned value from compute_curve() so probably should redefine that function to have a 'void' return type rather than a float return type

Answer (score 0):

Your prototype needs to declare a variable name too like `float compute_curve(float x)`, and your actual implementation definition should match that also.

Answer (score 0):

```
float compute_curve(float f)
```

f itself does not name a type, "float" does. The prototype uses "float", which made your compiler give you an error about unmatching declarations rather than how "f" isn't a type, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

here are the significant warnings that the compiler raises (and that need fixing)

in function: main()
  -- return type defaults to int

in function: compute_curve()
  -- parameter 'f' defaults to int
  -- parameter 'f' does not match prototype
  -- control reaches end of non-void function

The following is what the code should look like

(with suitable indentation and error checking)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *fp;


void compute_curve(float);

int main()
{
    float f = 1.0f;

    if(NULL == (fp = fopen("Curve", "w") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for Curve failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    printf("Hello");

    while (f != 0.0f)
    {
        printf("Input a Float value(0 to quit): ");
        if( 1 != (scanf("%f", &f) ) )
        { // scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for float value failed" );
            fclose( fp ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        compute_curve(f);
    } // end while

    fclose(fp); // cleanup
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void compute_curve(float f)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n<4096; n *= 2)
    {
        float Speedup = 1.0f / (( 1.0f - f ) + (f / (float)n));
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n",n) ;
        fprintf(fp, "%f\n", Speedup) ;
    } // end for
} // end function: compute_curve
```